# Parsing PL/SQL code to check against syntax and semantic errors

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

Please consider following scenario:

- I have a **Text-Area** and a **Button** on UI.
- User will enter a PL/SQL block in **Text-Area**.
- When user will press **Button**, I want to check for syntax and semantic errors in that block without **executing** it.

I would really like a solution where I don't have to install anything more.

Environment information:

1. Java 1.6.31
2. Oracle database 11g

Comment: is that a requirement for SO to solve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3970643/85371; You can always ask for an explain plan. That won't be without server load, but it won't execute the statement either (and check the validity of all names referenced)

Comment: unless you use some 3rd party library, you will have to write your own custom rules and apply them over the query string

Comment: @MihaiC I thought so but i will stick around just in case. :)

Comment: Maybe the discussion on [akstom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3648254441315) will help?

Comment: Are you parsing anonymous blocks or potentially create procedure/function statements? It's [almost impossible to disable PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182315/how-to-disable-pl-sql-in-oracle-queries), but you could determine the type first. It'll be very difficult to prevent people executing DDL, not matter what you do.

Answer (score 3):

```
SQL> explain plan for select from dual;
explain plan for select from dual
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression


SQL> explain plan for select * from dual;

Explained.
```

or

```
declare
  c integer := dbms_sql.open_cursor();
begin
 dbms_sql.parse(c, 'select * emp', dbms_sql.native);
 dbms_sql.close_cursor(c);
end;
/
Error at line 1
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1053
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

or hit http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/EasySQL-Checker-for-Oracle.shtml

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult and you probably have to consider all kind of possiblities and make sure that the users do not wreck you database by making sure to grant very little rights etc. You got the point.

This is not the full solution but it points you into the right direction.

You could try to embed it into a `CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE` and fetch errors. Something like this:

```
declare
  text_area varchar2(4000) := 'declare x number; begin xy := x + 1; end;';
begin
  execute immediate 'create or replace procedure DUMMY#__ IS BEGIN null; begin '|| text_area ||' end; END;';
exception
    -- see comment below about error handling
    when others then 
        -- signal yourself it went wrong
        RAISE;   
end;
```

The trouble with an anonymous block would be that it is right away executed. But that way you only execute a createion of the procedure which does the compile. If you have several users you probably want to create different procedure names or you want to create different schemas even to prevent conflicts. As I said this is not the full solution but just pointing into some direction.

"ORA-23344 success with compilation error" can be used to fetch compile errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a PL/SQL interpreter. It can check the given almost the syntax of the code.
If you want to get full check, it is not easy, you have to check the DB objects, properties. permissions etc.

You can create yourself a PL/SQL interpreter to ensure you requirements, OR you can try this parser: https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser

By the way, I will be in trouble with "execute immediate" -calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you do have access to a running Oracle system which contains the tables in question, you can use `dbms_sql.parse()` to check if a given piece of SQL is valid or not.

Regular DML statements are not execute through `parse()`, but DDL **will** be executed immediately. So you might want to check if the SQL is not a DDL statement (or better, only allow certain statements to begin with).

Note that if the database you are connecting to, does not contain the tables used in the SQL, `parse()` *will* throw an error even if the statement is syntactically correct.